# Saving via Entity Framework takes a lot of resources

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I'm using Sql Server Db conntected to my ASP.NET Mvc Application via Entity Framework.
Application is deployed on Virtual Machine, which is managing by Cluster. Curently max memory is setup to 32 GB. I could up it to 64 GB.
One of avaliable solution for users is loading `csv` files to database. Every single file is one day, which is consisting of **80-90k records with 200 columns.** For this solution I used this setup:

```cs
public ActionResult AddRecordsFromCSVFile2(FileInput fileInputs)
        {
            BWSERWISEntities bWDiagnosticEntities2 = new BWSERWISEntities();
            bWDiagnosticEntities2.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
            bWDiagnosticEntities2.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

            var Files = fileInputs.File;
            if (ModelValidate())
            {
                foreach (var fileInput in Files)
                {
                    List<VOLTER_LOGS> LogsToAdd = new List<VOLTER_LOGS>();
                    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        fileInput.InputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        {
                            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
                            {
                                var csvConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                                {
                                    Delimiter = ";",
                                    HasHeaderRecord = false
                                };
                                using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader, csvConfig))
                                {
                                    var records = csvReader.GetRecords<ReadAllRecords>().ToList();
                                    var firstRecord = records.Where(x => x.Parametr4 != "0" && x.Parametr5 != "0" && x.Parametr6 != "0").FirstOrDefault();
                                    var StartDateToCheck = Convert.ToDateTime(firstRecord.Parametr4 + "-" + firstRecord.Parametr5 + "-" + firstRecord.Parametr6 + " " + firstRecord.Parametr3 + ":" + firstRecord.Parametr2 + ":" + firstRecord.Parametr1, new CultureInfo("en-GB", true));
                                    var lastRecord = records.Where(x => x.Parametr4 != "0" && x.Parametr5 != "0" && x.Parametr6 != "0").LastOrDefault();
                                    var EndDateToCheck = Convert.ToDateTime(lastRecord.Parametr4 + "-" + lastRecord.Parametr5 + "-" + lastRecord.Parametr6 + " " + lastRecord.Parametr3 + ":" + lastRecord.Parametr2 + ":" + lastRecord.Parametr1, new CultureInfo("en-GB", true));
                                    int matchingMachineID = int.Parse(firstRecord.Parametr7);
                                    var matchingElements = bWDiagnosticEntities2.VOLTER_LOGS.Where(x => (x.Parametr7 == matchingMachineID) && (x.Parametr1 >= StartDateToCheck && x.Parametr1 <= EndDateToCheck)).ToList();
                                    bWDiagnosticEntities2.VOLTER_LOGS.RemoveRange(matchingElements);
                                    bWDiagnosticEntities2.SaveChanges();                                
                                    foreach (var record in records)
                                    {
                                        if (record.Parametr4 != "0" && record.Parametr5 != "0" && record.Parametr6 != "0")
                                        {
                                            bWDiagnosticEntities2.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
                                            string date = record.Parametr4 + "-" + record.Parametr5 + "-" + record.Parametr6 + " " + record.Parametr3 + ":" + record.Parametr2 + ":" + record.Parametr1;
                                            DateTime recordDate = DateTime.Parse(date, new CultureInfo("en-GB", true));
                                            // DateTime recordDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
                                            VOLTER_LOGS vOLTER_LOGS = new VOLTER_LOGS();
                                            vOLTER_LOGS.Parametr1 = recordDate;
                                            vOLTER_LOGS.Parametr2 = 0;
                                            vOLTER_LOGS.Parametr3 = 0;
                                            vOLTER_LOGS.Parametr4 = 0;
                                            vOLTER_LOGS.Parametr5 = 0;
                                            vOLTER_LOGS.Parametr6 = 0;
                                            vOLTER_LOGS.Parametr7 = int.Parse(record.Parametr7);

7-200...
                                            vOLTER_LOGS.Parametr200 = int.Parse(record.Parametr200);

                                            LogsToAdd.Add(vOLTER_LOGS);
                                           
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        bWDiagnosticEntities2.VOLTER_LOGS.AddRange(LogsToAdd);
                        bWDiagnosticEntities2.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
            }    
            return View();
        }
```

This implementation takes **5-8 mins** and taking like **45-55%** of VM's memory, but during the save process sometimes is difficult to get response of other simple request (get first and last date) with error:

```
The request limited has expired or server is not responding.
```

Server has a lot of free memory, but table has a 7kk records already and still growing up.
Finalny propably files won't be save during the other users requests.
Now i'm wondering that is it good idea to use Entity Framework for that data volume.
The main goal of Application is to detect errors in data volume over a period of time.
Does anyone happen to have experience with such amount of data processing via Entity Framework?
Is any solution to split resources to every single task, so that every request could get response?

Comment: It's not EF's fault. That's not its job. Using a hammer to drive screws etc. EF's job is to load graphs of related entities  and give the impression of working with objects instead of databases. In ETL jobs like this there are no entities, there are tables, rows, fields,files

Comment: What is the file's format? What does it contain and what does the target table look like? The fastest way to import data in bulk is to use the SqlBulkCopy class with an IDataReader input. If the data source provides an IDataReader you won't have to cache a lot of data in memory. If eg you use ExcelDataReader, you can pass the `IDataReader` object it provides directly to `SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync`. SqlBulkCopy performs a BULK INSERT, a special minimally-logged INSERT operation using a stream of input data

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Okay, so for the main goal EF should be effective. In your opinion, which solution will be fast and effective for saving data?

Comment: What do you want to do with that data? Why not use `bcp` or `BULK INSERT` with those files? That's the fastest. Using SqlBulkCopy from C# is almost as fast and uses the same mechanism. Do you want to transform the data while loading though? Or is it enough to insert it into a staging table and then process it?

Comment: CsvHelper can [create an IDataReader too](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/csvdatareader/) and ExcelDataReader can also read CSVs.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ```csv``` files contains 200 numbers so table is mirror 1:1 where just 1 property is DateTime, the others are ints. I will put my saving method to edited post.

Comment: Are you simply importing the files or do you have to perform any processing?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm importing files then i'm processing 6 string to 1 DateTime and 194 strings to 194 ints and then saving to db. Let me edit post.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I just edited post, I added my saving method.

Comment: Try to execute the job in smaller chunks that each use a new context. The entire operation can be wrapped in a TransactionScope.

Comment: @GertArnold Okay, I will try it also, maybe 10k packs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF is an ORM, not an import tool. An ORM's job is to load graphs of related entities and give the impression of working with objects instead of tables and SQL. There are no entities or graphs in import jobs though, there are files, fields, tables and mappings.

The fastest way to import data SQL Server tables in .NET is to use the [SqlBulkCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) class. This uses the same mechanism used in the `bcp` tool or the `BULK INSERT` command to import data as a stream, using minimal logging. The input can be a DataTable or an IDataReader instance.

Libraries like [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/csvdatareader/) or [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) provide IDataReader-derived classes out of the box. In other cases, [FastMember](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member)'s ObjectReader can be used to create an IDataReader wrapper over any IEnumerable.

Loading a CSV into a table with CsvHelper and SqlBulkCopy could be as simple as this, provided the file and table columns match:

```
public async Task SimpleImport(string path, string table, 
                               string connectionString)
{
    using var reader = new StreamReader(path);
    var csvConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        {
            Delimiter = ";"
        };
    using var csv = new CsvReader( reader, csvConfig);

    using var dr = new CsvDataReader(csv);
    using var bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString);
    bcp.DestinationTableName = table;

    await bcp.WriteToServerAsync(dr);
}
```

If there are no headers, they'll have to be provided through CsvHelper's configuration, eg through `GetDynamicPropertyName` or a class map :

```
string[] fields=new[] {.....};
csvConfig.GetDynamicPropertyName = args=> {
    if (args.FieldIndex<10)
    {
        return fields[args.FieldIndex];
    }
    else
    {
        return $"Value_{args.FieldIndex}";
    }
};
```

Using a ClassMap allows specifying type conversions, including complex ones

```
public class Foo
{
    ...
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooMap()
    {
        AutoMap(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        Map(m => m.Date).Convert(row => DateFromParts(row.GetField(5),row.GetField(6),row.GetField(7));
    }

    DateTime DateFromParts(string year, string month, string say)
    {
        return DateTime.Parse($"{year}-{month}-{day}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay i will try to use it. Can I use both? SqlBulkCopy and EF? I would like use EF to delete range to avoid duplicate Data in db.

Comment: You'd have to load or create those objects then `Remove` them. It would be a *lot* faster to insert the PKs into a staging table then execute a `DELETE target from target inner join del_ids on target.ID=del_ids.ID`. You can fill the staging table using SqlBulkCopy too. If there are ~1000 items you could use `DELETE target where ID in (...)`. You can execute that using `FromSqlRaw`, or use eg Dapper to execute `connection.Execute("delete target where ID in (@ids)",listOfIds);`

Comment: Okay So i'm going to test it.

Comment: Working well, thank you :)